# How to add url parameters to elasticsearch UpdateByQuery in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have a nodejs app that calls ES's updateByQuery API like below:

```
elasticsearchClient.updateByQuery({
            index: 'logstash-dev-2019.05.14',
            body: {
                "query": {
                    "ids": {
                        "values": alert.esId
                    }
                },
                "script": {
                    "source": `ctx._source.alertObject.violation_status = 'closed'`,
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        });
```

However occasionally, I run into `version_conflict_engine_exception`. I want to proceed with the conflict by using `conflict=proceed` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query). Where do I fit this into my update call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querystring` object as provided in the [docs](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js), please  scroll to the end of the link.

```
elasticsearchClient.updateByQuery({
  index: 'logstash-dev-2019.05.14',
  querystring: {
    "conflict": "proceed"
  },
  body: {
    "query": {
      "ids": {
        "values": alert.esId
      }
    },
    "script": {
       "source": `ctx._source.alertObject.violation_status = 'closed'`,
       "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @blueren All parameters should be passed to this object. Example: `querystring: {
    "conflict": "proceed",
    "foo": "bar"
  },`